# Trait implementation not being inferenced correctly when defined via macro

Tags: json, rust

I've been working with the `json` crate ([GitHub](https://github.com/maciejhirsz/json-rust), [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/json)), and I decided to implement a helper function for parsing numbers out of json:

```rust
use std::convert::{TryInto, From, Infallible};
use json::number::Number;
use json::{self, JsonValue, JsonError};
use std::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ConvertError {
    JsonError(JsonError),
    InfallibleError(Infallible),
    InvalidTypeError
}
impl fmt::Display for ConvertError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::JsonError(e) => e.fmt(f),
            Self::InfallibleError(e) => e.fmt(f),
            Self::InvalidTypeError => write!(f, "Field has an invalid type")
        }
    }
}
impl Error for ConvertError {}
impl From<JsonError> for ConvertError {
    fn from(e: JsonError) -> Self {
        Self::JsonError(e)
    }
}
impl From<Infallible> for ConvertError {
    fn from(e: Infallible) -> Self {
        Self::InfallibleError(e)
    }
}

fn test_num<T: From<Number>>(obj: JsonValue) -> Result<T, ConvertError> {
    match obj {
        JsonValue::Number(num) => Ok(num.try_into()?),
        _ => Err(ConvertError::InvalidTypeError)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let s = "{\"test_float\": 0.1, \"test_int1\": 1, \"test_int2\": 2}";
    let mut parsed = json::parse(s)?;

    // Works (From<f32> defined here: https://docs.rs/json/0.12.4/src/json/number.rs.html#344-361)
    let num1: f32 = test_num(parsed["test_float"].take())?;
    // Also works
    let num2: i32 = match parsed["test_int1"].take() {
        JsonValue::Number(num) => match num.try_into() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            _ => return Err(Box::new(ConvertError::InvalidTypeError))
        },
        _ => return Err(Box::new(ConvertError::InvalidTypeError))
    };
    // Doesn't work (From<i32> defined here: https://docs.rs/json/0.12.4/src/json/number.rs.html#495)
    let num3: i32 = test_num(parsed["test_int2"].take())?;

    println!("Number 1: {}", num1);
    println!("Number 2: {}", num2);
    println!("Number 3: {}", num3);

    Ok(())
}
```

When I try to compile the program, however, the following error is returned:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: From<json::number::Number>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:56:21
   |
34 | fn test_num<T: From<Number>>(obj: JsonValue) -> Result<T, ConvertError> {
   |                ------------ required by this bound in `test_num`
...
56 |     let num3: i32 = test_num(parsed["test_int2"].take())?;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<json::number::Number>` is not implemented for `i32`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <i32 as From<NonZeroI32>>
             <i32 as From<bool>>
             <i32 as From<i16>>
             <i32 as From<i8>>
           and 2 others
```

What's particularly interesting is `let num1: f32 = test_num(parsed["test_float"].take())?;` and inlining the function do *not* have compile errors, while the `i32` variant *does*.
From what I can tell, the only difference between the `From<f32>` and `From<i32>` implementations is that `i32` is implemented [via a macro](https://github.com/maciejhirsz/json-rust/blob/master/src/number.rs#L404-L496).

Is this an error in the way I used the trait implementation, an error in the way the macro is implemented, or a compiler bug?

(I'm currently using the most up-to-date nightly compiler: `rustc 1.48.0-nightly (8b4085359 2020-09-23)`)

Comment: The macro implements `From<i32> for Number` and `TryFrom<Number> for i32`, but not `From<Number> for i32`.

Comment: Ah you're right not sure how I misread that, but it opens up a whole other can of worms since `TryFrom<Number>::Error` is `NumberOutOfScope`, which doesn't implement `std::error::Error`, so I haven't been able to use `?` for implicit conversions like I've been doing in main, I'll self answer once I figure it out if no one else has answered it by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @trentcl posted in the comments, only `TryFrom<Number>` is implemented for `i32`, not `From<Number>`. This actually made things a bit more complex because `TryFrom<Number>::Error` is `NumberOutOfScope`, which implements neither `std::error::Error` nor `std::fmt::Debug`.

Once all those issues are handled, the new function becomes:

```rust
fn test_num<T: TryFrom<Number>>(obj: JsonValue) -> Result<T, ConvertError<T>> {
    match obj {
        JsonValue::Number(num) => Ok(match num.try_into() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(e) => return Err(ConvertError::TryFromError(e))
        }),
        _ => Err(ConvertError::InvalidTypeError)
    }
}
```

and it can be used for `i32` and the other number types:

```rust
let num2: i32 = test_num(parsed["test_int1"].take())?;
```

Full code for reference:

```rust
use std::convert::{TryInto, TryFrom, Infallible};
use json::number::Number;
use json::{self, JsonValue, JsonError};
use std::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

enum ConvertError<T: TryFrom<Number>> {
    JsonError(JsonError),
    InfallibleError(Infallible),
    TryFromError(T::Error),
    InvalidTypeError
}
impl<T: TryFrom<Number>> fmt::Display for ConvertError<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::JsonError(e) => std::fmt::Display::fmt(&e, f),
            Self::InfallibleError(e) => std::fmt::Display::fmt(&e, f),
            Self::TryFromError(_) => write!(f, "TryFrom failed"),
            Self::InvalidTypeError => write!(f, "Field has an invalid type")
        }
    }
}
impl<T: TryFrom<Number>> fmt::Debug for ConvertError<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::JsonError(e) => std::fmt::Debug::fmt(&e, f),
            Self::InfallibleError(e) => std::fmt::Debug::fmt(&e, f),
            Self::TryFromError(_) => write!(f, "ConvertError::TryFromError"),
            Self::InvalidTypeError => write!(f, "ConvertError::InvalidTypeError"),
        }
    }
}
impl<T: TryFrom<Number>> Error for ConvertError<T> {}
impl<T: TryFrom<Number>> From<JsonError> for ConvertError<T> {
    fn from(e: JsonError) -> Self {
        Self::JsonError(e)
    }
}
impl<T: TryFrom<Number>> From<Infallible> for ConvertError<T> {
    fn from(e: Infallible) -> Self {
        Self::InfallibleError(e)
    }
}

fn test_num<T: TryFrom<Number>>(obj: JsonValue) -> Result<T, ConvertError<T>> {
    match obj {
        JsonValue::Number(num) => Ok(match num.try_into() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(e) => return Err(ConvertError::TryFromError(e))
        }),
        _ => Err(ConvertError::InvalidTypeError)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let s = "{\"test_float\": 0.1, \"test_int1\": 1}";
    let mut parsed = json::parse(s)?;

    let num1: f32 = test_num(parsed["test_float"].take())?;
    let num2: i32 = test_num(parsed["test_int1"].take())?;

    println!("Number 1: {}", num1);
    println!("Number 2: {}", num2);

    Ok(())
}
```